Otel-collector not able to accept rabbitmq-prometheus plugin metrics
I am working on apache skywalking with OAP, otel collector, banyandb. I want rabbitmq-prometheus metrics (http://localhost:15692/metrics/) should scraped and export by the OTel Collector. At the end i want these metrics for creating alarm rules in apache skywalking.
there is a metrics called rabbitmq_queue_messages_unacked coming from rabbitmq-prometheus . But otel-collector is not able to scrape it. I am getting below error in OAP docker container->
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.skywalking.mqe.rt.exception.IllegalExpressionException: Expression: sum(rabbitmq_queue_messages_unacked) > 100 error: Metric: [rabbitmq_queue_messages_unacked] does not exist.
It would be really appreciating if you provide me some example or doc.
otel-collector-config.yaml file
receivers:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: 'rabbitmq-monitoring'
          metrics_path: "/metrics"
          scrape_interval: 5s
          static_configs:
            - targets: ['ip:15692']

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: ip:11800
    tls:
      insecure: true

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [prometheus]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp]

Let me know if you need more details.
Thank you in advance.
